# Stop Safari extension from caching messages

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm having problems with creating a safari extension that has been causing me headaches.

The problem is this: I have created an extension that gets images from a web page using an injected script. I have a function in the popover that displays the web images and allows the user to click and send the selected image to a backend.  This all goes through the global page which handles signals and messages. The scenario is this:

1. When the popover opens, it sends a signal to the global page to initiate the response (image URLs) from the injected script.
2. When the global page gets the message from the injected script, it calls the function in the popover passing in the data from the injected script as an argument.
3. The popover shows all images returned from the global page via the injected script.

The problem is that every time I open the popover, it appends the images from the last call instead of giving a fresh list of images. For instance, on first popover open, I get one image (assuming the page has only one image). If I close the popover and open it again, I get two of the same image. If I close and open the popover a third time, it appends the first image with the one from the second time and gives me 3 of the same image.  On the fourth open of the popover I get 1 + 1 + 1 + 1, so 4 images. So it seems to be appending the messages and not giving me a fresh message every time.

My question is: how can I destroy the messages that are being cached after each popover closes? I hope I am being clear. Perhaps something else is happening with my code that I am not aware of. Please help if you can.  Here is my code from the global HTML:

```
function popoverHandler(event) {
  //check for popover opening
  if (event.target.identifier === "MyPopUp") {
    //send message to injected script to send page info
    safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.page.dispatchMessage("getContent", '', false);
    //this works fine, I get this message every time popover opens  
    console.log('getContent message sent');
    //listen for message containing page info from injected script  
    safari.application.addEventListener('message', function (messageEvent) {
      //only get message from current tab
      if (messageEvent.name === "pageInfo" && messageEvent.message.url === safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url) {
        pageInfo = messageEvent.message;
        //the problem seems to be in here.  Every time I open the popover, //I get the current page info plus all the page info messages from //the previous time I open the pover, all duplicates of the previous //messges
        console.log(pageInfo);

        // call a function in the popover, passing the pageInfo data //received from the injected script
        safari.extension.popovers[0].contentWindow.onPageDetailsReceived(pageInfo);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to solve the problem. First of all, I separated the popoverHandler from the eventListener.  For some reason, it was firing the function too many times and returning several lists of the same images.  The major issue, however, was that in the popover.js, I was storing the list of images as a var.  When I removed the var, the data stopped persisting and I was getting a fresh list every time.